# How to convert date string "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ" to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a CSV file with timestamps such as `2018-04-04T00:03:04Z`. I created a table with a timestamp field and fill the table with the data from CSV, but an error is generated:

> Incorrect datetime value

and my table isn't filled at all; doing a select query returns 0 rows.

I tried to use `str_to_date(date_sale, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`  but it returned null values.

Earlier I created the table with the date field as a string and everything goes right, but now I need to convert this field in a timestamp field anyway in order to manipulate the date. I'm filling the table with the *Table Data Import Wizard*.

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: The Z means time-zone information should be included.

Comment: BTW, never store date/time data in varchar columns. Use proper date/time data types!

Comment: Your columns are of varchar type. You just need to modify it. `ALTER TABLE nf MODIFY date_sale timestamp`. But you need to format your dates before it

Comment: @jarlh I tried to replace the Z by CET and apply the str_to_date again and the result is null values. I already tried to create the table with timestamp field but then I can't fill the table with the CSV file.

Comment: Is PHP an option? Do you want to convert the data to local time?

Comment: @RomanSamrsky How I should format the date if it's a string field?
I already tried to create the table with timestamp field but then I can't fill the table with the CSV file.

Comment: Hello @SalmanA, no PHP isn't an option, just SQL. I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @RomanSamrsky I tried run the ```ALTER TABLE``` but this error returns:
ALTER TABLE nf MODIFY date_sale timestamp Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2018-04-04T00:03:04Z' for column 'date_sale' at row 1 0.047 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If converting to local time is not necessary you could just use `str_to_time` with correct format:

```
select str_to_date('2018-04-04T00:03:04Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ')
-- 2018-04-04 00:03:04
```

If the timezone conversion is required then you must make sure that [timezone related tables are setup correctly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) then use `convert_tz` function:

```
select convert_tz(str_to_date('2018-04-04T00:03:04Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), 'zulu', 'system')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said at first you should update your dates to valid format:

```sql
UPDATE nf
SET
  date_delivery = DATE_FORMAT(
    STR_TO_DATE(date_delivery, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%I'
  ),
  date_sale = DATE_FORMAT(
    STR_TO_DATE(date_sale, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%I'
  )
WHERE 1;
```

After this step you need to modify your table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE nf
    MODIFY date_sale TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFY date_delivery TIMESTAMP;
```

And when you are inserting data don't forget to format it:

```sql
INSERT INTO nf (id, id_produt, id_category, date_sale, date_delivery)
VALUES
(31, 3, 4, STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-12T00:24Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-12T00:24:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%iZ:%s')),
(44, 3, 4, STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-12T00:24Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-12T00:24:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%iZ:%s'))
```

This way is better because you can operate your data as datetime format in sql.

For example if you have timestamp formats in DB than next query does not compare your string date_sale with the string '2013-12-12':

```sql
SELECT * FROM nf WHERE date_sale > '2013-12-12';
```

Comment: I'm not able to do that because I'm using Table Data Import Wizard as I said in the post.

Comment: @GabrielaBaldiviaSoncini ok, sorry. I missed it

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in a string **dd-mm-yyyy** or **d-m-y** then you first need to convert the string into the same date format. Then reformat the resulting date into the format the server uses for **DATE_SUB** i.e  **%Y-%m-d**. This way you are ensuring you are comparing a date to a date, so  use **CURDATE** instead of **NOW**. The statement is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_format(str_to_date(str_date_searched, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')  >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
```